# CMake static library dependencies not propagating with ExternalProject_Add

Tags: c, linker, cmake

I'm currently in the process of trying to get an executable to link properly with all the dependencies it needs.

Here is an example structure of the dependencies:

```
exe -> libA -> libB
```

`exe` and `libA` have their own repositories. `exe` pulls in `libA` something like this:

```
add_executable(exe ${sources})

ExternalProject_Add(
    libA
    GIT_REPOSITORY http://some/git/url/libA.git
    ...
)

target_include_directories(exe PRIVATE ${libA_includes})
target_link_libraries(exe ${libA_libs}/libA.a)

add_dependencies(exe libA)
```

`libA` pulls in `libB` in a similar fashion:

```
add_library(libA STATIC ${sources})

ExternalProject_Add(
    libB
    URL http://some/artifact/repo/libB.tgz
    ...
)

target_include_directories(libA PRIVATE ${libB_includes})
target_link_libraries(libA ${libB_libs}/libB.a)

add_dependencies(libA libB)
```

I can build `libA` fine, along with a test executable that properly links against `libB`. However, when I try to build `exe`, it only links against `libA` but not `libB`. How can I get CMake to know that the dependency between `libA` and `libB` shouldn't be lost through ExternalProject?

Edit:

I've created some dependency graphs to hopefully clarify what I want:

Actual:

[image: exe actual] [image: libA actual]

What I expect:

[image: expected]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit 2:

I ended up using the following as a solution:

In libA's CMakeLists.txt (where `${MODULE_NAME}` is some module's name within libA):

```
export(TARGETS ${MODULE_NAME}
       NAMESPACE "${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}-"
       APPEND FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}-targets.cmake)
```

In exe's CMakeLists.txt:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    libA ...
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(libA source_dir)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(libA binary_dir)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${source_dir})

set(LIBA_TARGETS_FILE ${binary_dir}/libA-targets.cmake)
if(EXISTS ${LIBA_TARGETS_FILE})
    include(${LIBA_TARGETS_FILE})
    target_link_libraries(${MODULE_NAME} libA-module_in_liba)
endif()

add_dependencies(${MODULE_NAME} libA)
```

Note: this does now require the project to be built using two runs of `cmake` as follows:

```
mkdir build; cd build
cmake .. # initial configuration
make # download the external projects
cmake .. # be able to include targets cmake file from external projects
make # this should now link everything properly
```

Comment: my answer below is without having seen the chart :-) but i think i got you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to achieve what you want to do by using a single configure run and the ExternalProject functionality. You just seem to use `${libA_libs}/libA.a`, which is of course without any further information.  Since the projects libA and libB could come from totally different vendors, there is no way to tell at configure time from your main project that LibA even contains a link dependency libB (which is by incidence also built within libA).

I will assume the following that you want to use the (fairly natural) idea of transitive linking.
Depending on whether you develop libA/libB yourself, there are different options. I'll explain the "cleanest" way of doing this. The downside is that this needs modification of the libA project cmake as well. [if you can't do this, you will need to manually add the libB.a as link library hard-coded; i.e. work around transitivity.. sorry!]

The key to transitive linking is that you need to import the actual *target* created by CMake in `libA`, which then correctly has the `target_link_libraries` information to libB and all will work. The target configuration of `libA` can be provided using the [INSTALL](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/install.html?highlight=install#installing-targets)(.. [EXPORT](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/export.html?highlight=export) ) functionality in cmake, which then allows you to import the target using `find_package(LIBA CONFIG)`. then, your exe CMakeLists.txt should look like

```
find_package(LIBA CONFIG QUIET)
if (NOT LIBA_FOUND)
    AddExternalProject(libA .....)
    return
else()
    add_executable(exe ${sources})
    target_link_libraries(exe <libA-target-name>)
```

This will include libB at link time as well as set the right include path (if defined PUBLIC in `target_include_directories(libA PUBLIC ${LIBA_INCDIR}`..)

The key problem is that the addition of an external project at the *same configure run* of course cannot yield everything that will be set by find_package, as nothing is compiled/installed yet. The idea behind external project is that you tell it where to place stuff so you subsequently know where stuff should be found, but that unfortunately will never include transitive stuff like link libraries.

There are (as always) quicker and more dirty solutions, however, the "new" cmake way of modularizing packages and making them available as targets via find_package in CONFIG mode is the best and uncomplicated way to include cmake-aware projects into each other.

Comment: I've added the solution I used to the original question, but it was based off this answer.

Comment: Hey! That seems to work, although it has the feeling of being "dirty" :-) I just stumbled upon the 'EXPORT_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES' flag for the export command; as you've been inserting stuff in the libA CMakeLists.txt maybe try to insert that and have a look at the exported config files?!

Comment: Unfortunately I can only use CMake 2.8.11 due to our build servers, and that flag was I think added in 2.8.12. I tried it locally and didn't see any difference.

Comment: What makes it feel dirty to you? I think I was missing something in order to get the find_package to work properly.

Comment: dirty because: if you properly import a target, any public include directory will be used without having to write a line of code. also, including the XXx-targets.cmake file directly is not what you are supposed to do. instead, use find_package in combination with CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to have it look at the export location of libA for those files. the naming convention for the exported configurations are somewhat unprecise, i recommend using "<targetname_lowecase>-config.cmake"; see the docs for more info here.

Comment: I now have the `find_package` working, with one exception: when I build for multiple architectures, I create two folders: `build/mipsel` and `build/x86_64` (building using `cmake ../..`). The first build goes fine, but then on the second, it seems the `find_package` goes into the other architecture's build directory for the `libA-config.cmake` file, which causes incompatible linking. Is there a way to limit the search path? The documentation seems lacking...

Comment: Architecture's a mess :-) different build, different output folder, different CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.. no way around it. I also don't know of any ideal way to deal with that, you'll need to come up with your own "architecture directory" organisation. I'm e.g. using the binary dir root folder name as "suffix" path element to construct my prefix path. But that's simply a matter of taste and/or discipline.